# Find all the homomorphisms from $C_3$ to $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Find all the homomorphisms from $C_3$ to $A_4$.

I know that $C_3=\{1,c,c^2\}$ and $A_4$ is the group of even permutations on four elements.

So let $\lambda:C_3\rightarrow A_4$ be a homomorphism. Then $\lambda$ has to have this property $\lambda(c_1c_2)=\lambda(c_1)\lambda(c_2)$ for $c_1,c_2\in C_3$.

I'm guessing that I have to first find how many there are, then trial and error until I find them all?

How do I find how many there are and is there a method to finding them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every homomorphisms $C_3 \to A_4$ is either trivial or injective (because $C_3$ is simple), and the non-trivial homomorphisms correspond bijectively to the elements of order $3$, which we can easily find by using the [cycle decomposition](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_alternating_group:A4#Multiple_ways_of_describing_permutations); the elements of order $3$ are
$$
 a_2 = (1,2,3), \;
 a_3 = (1,3,2), \;
 a_4 = (1,2,4), \;
 a_5 = (1,4,2), \\
 a_6 = (1,3,4), \;
 a_7 = (1,4,3), \;
 a_8 = (2,3,4), \;
 a_9 = (2,4,3).
$$
Together with $a_1 = 1$ we get nine homomorphisms $C_3 \to A_4$, each uniquely described by $1 \mapsto a_i$.

(Instead of looking at the cycle decomposition of each element we could also use the Sylow theorems to find that $A_4$ has four subgroups of order $3$, each of which gives us two elements of order $3$, resulting in the above eight elements.)